# Spriogboot file upload Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring-boot

I am getting {"message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","statusCode":500} error while uploading file in springboot. There are many input fields on my form and one of the field is file upload. Below is the html Image:
[image]

Ajex Code:

```
function UploadManager(ctx) {
this.context = ctx;
this.uploadTrainingURL = this.context.MonitorAddressNew + "/maintenance/uploadTraining/" + this.context.OrgID + "/" + this.context.UserID;
var that = this;

this.Upload = function (info, link, trainingItem, saveCallback) {
let that = this;
    let fdata = new FormData();

    let name = $("#inputUploadFile").val();
    fdata.append("tfile", name);

    $.each($("#inputUploadFile")[0].files, function (i, file) {
        fdata.append('file' + i, file);
    });

    //this.StartWait("Creating " + $("#inputUploadFile").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: that.uploadTrainingURL,
        data: fdata,
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: "true"
        }, crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            that.UploadStatus(data, { "name": $("#inputUploadFile").val(), "file": $("#inputUploadFile")[0].files[0].name }, info, link, trainingItem, saveCallback);
        },
        error: function (errorData) {
            that.UploadError(errorData);
        }
    });
}
```

SpringBoot Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadTraining/{organizationID}/{userID}")
UploadTrainingResult uploadTraining(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile fname,
                                    @PathVariable("organizationID") String organizationID,
                                    @PathVariable("userID") String userID)
```

I am able to upload file using postman.but integrating through UI is not working. I am am a backend developer have a little knowledge in Frontend . can anyone please help me out what I am missing here. Ajex code is written by someone else who is not present now.

Thanks,
Prabhash

Comment: Your jquery script looks a bit weird to me :D  It should look similar 

`const formData = new FormData();
  const files = document.querySelector('#file').files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    formData.append('file', files[0]);
  }`